# I cant set text in textView by using bundle String data that pass from Activity to fragment

Tags: java, android, textview, bundle

> Data pass from ProjectDetailActivity to ProjectDetailFragment ,I already check that data can pass to fragment by using Toast to show data as you can see in the code , but the problem is I cant set text in Textview by using data from bundle . If you see some error in this code please let me know . Thank a lot.

***ProjectDetailActivity Class***

```
         private String project_key,project_name,project_priority,project_category,
                        project_start_date ,project_end_date,project_description;
         @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.activity_project_detail);

              Intent intent = getIntent();
              project_key         = intent.getStringExtra("project_key");
              project_name        = intent.getStringExtra("project_name");
              project_category    = intent.getStringExtra("project_category");
              project_priority    = intent.getStringExtra("project_priority");

              Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
              bundle.putString("project_key",project_key);
              bundle.putString("project_name",project_name);
              bundle.putString("project_category",project_category);
              bundle.putString("project_priority",project_priority);

              ProjectDetailFragment project_detail_fragment =new ProjectDetailFragment();
              project_detail_fragment.setArguments(bundle);
              getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.project_detail_fragment,project_detail_fragment)
                .commit();

          }
     }
```

***ProjectDetailFragment Class***

```
 public class ProjectDetailFragment extends Fragment {
      private View root;

      private String project_key,project_name,project_priority,project_category,


      private TextView project_name_textView , project_priority_textView ,
                       project_category_textView ;

      private Context mContext;

      public ProjectDetailFragment() { }

      @Override
      public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           if (getArguments() != null) {
                Bundle bundle = getArguments();
                project_key           = bundle.getString("project_key");
                project_name          = bundle.getString("project_name");
                project_priority      = bundle.getString("project_category");
                project_category      = bundle.getString("project_priority");
           }
      }

      public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle 
                  savedInstanceState) {
            root =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_project_detail, container,false);

            project_name_textView        = root.findViewById(R.id.project_name_textView);
            project_priority_textView    = root.findViewById(R.id.priority_textView);
            project_category_textView    = root.findViewById(R.id.category_textView);


            project_name_textView.setText(project_name);
            project_priority_textView.setText(project_priority);
            project_category_textView.setText(project_category);

            Toast.makeText(mContext,"TASK ACTIVITY\n"+
                    project_key+"\n"+project_name+"\n"+project_category+"\n"
                    +project_priority+"\n",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return root;
       }

       @Override
       public void onAttach(Context context) {
            super.onAttach(context);
            mContext=context;
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if Toast is showing you data it means there is no problem in receiving the data and i can see no error in setting the data to text view, but check your xml, check the text color if text color is matching with background color , for example the text-view background is white and text color is also white, obviously than you can not see the text.
or if not you can try it like this::::  project_name_textView.setText(String.value of(project_name));

Comment: Thank for ur guiding. Now I fix on XML file cause I use too many layout  in ProjectDetailFragment XML that the reason that I couldn't see the text that I set. So I already delete some layout and it work very well....